# Deserialize JSON to C# object does not assign the values

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, jsonconvert

I have below `Contacts JSON` data -

```
{
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "elementsOnPage": 0,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": "9bf83fab-a485-495c-8e1f-b32c8fe9b9c6",
            "version": 1,
            "type": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And below C# `Contacts` class to map with `JSON` -

```
public class Contacts
    {
       
        public System.Guid id { get; set; }

        public long version { get; set; }
      
        public ContactType type { get; set; }
    }
```

To `Deserialize` the `JSON`, I have written the code below -

```
Contacts contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contacts>(ContactsJson);
```

`json` is nothing but the `Contacts JSON` given above in `C#`.

Now, when I check `contacts object` all the values are `null`, no values are assigned to the `object properties`. Am I missing something? Please help or suggest.

**Note -** I don't want to get the values of `currentPage` , `totalPages`, `elementsOnPage` and `totalElements`

TIA

Comment: Where are is the type definitions for the fields in the parent object (ie currentPage and the array of contacts)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Contacts contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contacts>(ContactsJson);
```

The DeserializeObject expects the json to look like an instance of Contacts class. It does not matter if you are not interested in those things, the structure of the class must match the json. The json is an object that contains *many* Contacts. So it needs to match:

Try this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public System.Guid id { get; set; }
    public long version { get; set; }
    public ContactType type { get; set; }
}

public class ContactCollection
{
    public Contact[] contacts{ get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
var contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactCollection>(ContactsJson);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare your classes like this and it will deserialize.

```
public class Contact
{
    public Guid id { get; set; } 
    public int version { get; set; } 
    public int type { get; set; } 
}

public class Contacts
{
    public int totalElements { get; set; } 
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; } 
}
```

Since you are using using Newtonsoft JSON, Use this

```
Contacts contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contacts>(ContactsJson);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    var contacts = jObject.SelectToken("contacts").First.ToObject<Contacts>();
```

Assuming your class looks like this:

```
    public class Contacts
    {

        public Guid id { get; set; }

        public long version { get; set; }

        public int type { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var contacts = data["contacts"].ToObject<List<Contacts>>();
```

Contacts class

```
public class Contacts
{
    public System.Guid id { get; set; }
    public long version { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you change the contacts element from array to object in json file !

Comment: @NajiMakhoul It is possible to map each element or just take a specific element that I chose the second mode because of the question.